# VB.NET - For Each in WPF-Controls

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I want to check some childelements in my WPF-Form. In WindowsForms that was quite easy with (like):

```
For Each control as Textbox in Me
 control.text = "hello people"
Next
```

How do I do that in WPF within my XAML.VB-File? I got a listbox with some childelements here which I want to analyse.

Greetz and thanks for your ideas!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends.  Suppose you have a ListBox defined as:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox">
    <ListBoxItem>Item1</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>Item2</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>Item3</ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

You can get the ListBoxItems within it by just iterating through the Items collection as such:

```
For Each x As ListBoxItem In Me.listBox.Items
    Console.WriteLine(x.Content.ToString())
Next
```

However, this will not work if the items in the ListBox was defined via the ItemsSource property.  So if the items are defined like this:

```
    Dim itemsSource As New List(Of Object)
    itemsSource.Add("Object1")
    itemsSource.Add(200D)
    itemsSource.Add(DateTime.Now)
    Me.listBox.ItemsSource = itemsSource
```

you'll have to use the ItemContainerGenerator to get the actual ListBoxItem.

```
    For Each x In Me.listBox.Items
        Dim item As ListBoxItem = DirectCast(Me.listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(x), ListBoxItem)
        Console.WriteLine(item.Content.ToString())
    Next
```

Now, the examples above are specific to a ListBox control.  If you want a way to get all the items in the entire Visual Tree of a given control (e.g. the Window), you'll have to use the VisualTreeHelper.GetChild (as suggested by Brian).

Anyway, here's a little sample I wrote that might help you out.  It contains everything I described above.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <StackPanel x:Name="sp">
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox">
            <ListBoxItem>Item1</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item2</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item3</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>

        <Button x:Name="btnChange" Click="btnChange_Click">Change ItemsSource</Button>
        <Button x:Name="btnPrint" Click="btnPrint_Click">Print Items</Button>

        <Button x:Name="btnPrintVisualTree" Click="btnPrintVisualTree_Click">Print Visual Tree</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code-behind:

```
Class MainWindow 


    Private Sub Window_Loaded(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)

        'Get all ListBoxItems
        For Each x As ListBoxItem In Me.listBox.Items
            Console.WriteLine(x.Content.ToString())
        Next

        'Get all items in the StackPanel
        For Each y As UIElement In Me.sp.Children
            Console.WriteLine(y.ToString())
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnChange_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
        'Set an ItemsSource for the ListBox

        Me.listBox.Items.Clear()

        Dim itemsSource As New List(Of Object)
        itemsSource.Add("Object1")
        itemsSource.Add(200D)
        itemsSource.Add(DateTime.Now)
        Me.listBox.ItemsSource = itemsSource
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnPrint_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)

        'Print the items within the ListBox
        For Each x In Me.listBox.Items
            Dim item As ListBoxItem = DirectCast(Me.listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(x), ListBoxItem)
            Console.WriteLine(item.Content.ToString())
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnPrintVisualTree_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
        PrintVisualTreeRecursive(Me)
    End Sub

    Private Sub PrintVisualTreeRecursive(ByVal parent As DependencyObject)

        Console.WriteLine(parent.ToString())

        Dim count As Integer = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent)
        If count > 0 Then
            For n As Integer = 0 To count - 1
                Dim child As DependencyObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, n)
                PrintVisualTreeRecursive(child)
            Next
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use the `VisualTreeHelper.GetChild` method and call into it recursively to descend the tree. If you know the name of control you are looking for then you can use the `FrameworkElement.FindName` method. There is more information in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/636383/wpf-ways-to-find-controls) with plenty of options and example code.